# How to mention payment gateway charges in an invoice?

Tags: payment-terms, payments, invoices

I work for a client based in Great Britain, and I will be sending him an invoice for graphic design work that has already been completed. The payment will be made via PayPal, and he is willing to cover the payment gateway charges of PayPal.

So when I make the invoice, how shall I write the entry of the payment gateway charges in the invoice? What is the best procedure to follow when defining the additional charge on an invoice so that all transactions remain transparent to the client?

Your advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Be careful, if Paypal sees you are increasing charges to cover their fees, they will be unhappy. It's a long standing battle between merchants and payment gateways. The gateways do not want your customers thinking the gateway is charging more to use them - it reflects poorly on them, even if it's true. They expect you to eat the cost of the gateway. And the reality is.. if Paypal's 4% is too taxing on you, you aren't charging enough to begin with. If you go out to eat, and pay with a Visa, does the restaurant tack on an extra 4% because you handed them a Visa? No, the restaurant pays the fees.

Answer (score 1):

1)Enter this charge as a line item on the invoice describing exactly what it is per your post and enter the charge.

2)In the future, format your invoices to include a line for "additional charges" and then enter those charge that are specific to a specific client on that  line as indicated above in #1.

3)This is probably the simplest way unless/until you have a large number of clients and a fair percentage use specialized payment forms that have extra charges. In this case you can consider a separate line for "payment charges".

4)The simplest format using #1, #2 or #3 above is to put the reason for the charge/line item on the left and the amount on the right. This righthand column will consist of pluses and possibly minuses so that the customer can see the addup to the final charge clearly.